# Passing a style down to the child of a UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

So I'm writing a UserControl that is a composite of a couple other controls. Specifically a Chart, another custom date range control, and ContentPresenters to fill in other areas of the screen.

So I'm binding my Content presenters to dependency properties nicely with `{Binding ElementName=chartView, Path=RightContent}` and I figure if I want to pass down an optional data point style down to the actual charting control I could do something like `{Binding ElementName=chartView, Path=DataPointStyle}` to bind to a dependency property of type Style.

Sadly this gives me the error `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=chartView'. BindingExpression:Path=DataPointStyle; DataItem=null; target element is 'ColumnSeries' (Name=''); target property is 'DataPointStyle' (type 'Style')`

So I think there's some weird XAML scoping thing with how the Chart and ColumnSeries control works. It's the Chart control from the Feb 2010 WPF Toolkit, so if there's something more up to date I should be using anyway, that'd be cool to know too.

So basically:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyFramework.Controls.ChartView"
         x:Name="chartView"
         ...>

    ...

    <!-- Works great -->
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=chartView, Path=TopContent}" />

    <!-- Doesn't work -->
    <charting:Chart>
        <charting:ColumnSeries DataPointStyle="{Binding ElementName=chartView, Path=DataPointStyle}" />
        </charting:Chart>
    </charting:Chart>


    ...
</UserControl>
```

How do I make that second binding on the ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle work?

Answer (score 0):

I have never experienced such problem, but as a workaround you can try to use binding with `RelativeSource` and `FindAncestor` mode.

Comment: I have tried `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type controls:ChartView}}, Path=DataPointStyle}` but I still wind up with `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyFramework.Controls.ChartView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataPointStyle; DataItem=null; target element is 'ColumnSeries' (Name=''); target property is 'DataPointStyle' (type 'Style')`